# автоматическое выполнение команды перед сохранением файла

Tags: vim, vimrc

Подскажите как настроить автоматическое применение команды ClangFormat в редакторе VIM. Проблема в том, что на :ClangFormat у меня стоит форматирование кода и приходится постоянно прописывать сначала :ClangFormat, а потом :wq. Можно ли задать в параметре сохранения и выхода (:wq) еще и параметр форматирования?

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что вы хотите автоматически запустить команду `ClangFormat` перед сохранением файла?

Comment: да, правильно, хочу чтобы при сохранении файла автоматически вызывалась команда ClangFormat

Comment: В качестве дополнения к уже отмеченному ответу хочу добавить, что чтобы все время не прописывать вручную команду для форматирования (когда вы пока не хотите сохранить буфер, но хотите отфармотировать), можно переопределить комбинацию клавиш для этой опрерации. Например `autocmd FileType c,cpp nnoremap <buffer> <c-k> :call ClangFormat()<cr>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы выполнить команду автоматически по событию нужно воспользоваться автокомандами. В данном случае:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * :ClangFormat<CR>
```

Тут:

- `BufWritePre` событие непосредственно перед сохранением файла командой `:w`
- `*` - шаблон имени файла. Можно задать `*.cpp` или несколько типов через запятую `*.cpp,*.h`.

Эту команду можно либо выполнить вручную, тогда действие будет только в рамках текущей сессии (до закрытия vim). Чтобы она действовала всегда, нужно добавить команду в vimrc файл.

Его местоположение зависит от инсталяции (для юникс это `$HOME/.vimrc` или `$HOME/.vim/vimrc`). Самый простой способ его отредактировать, это выполнить команду:

```
:edit $MYVIMRC
```